# SQL query executed by ResultSet in Java is returning different values than when executed in database

Tags: java, sql, db2, prepared-statement, resultset

That's the query i'm running in database:

```
    SELECT CD_MAT, SUM(QT_MAT_UTIL) AS QT_MAT_UTIL FROM T476 
    WHERE (CD_UN_EXEC_SERV= 'X10' OR CD_UN_EXEC_SERV IN (SELECT 
    A.CD_UN_ORGANIZ FROM T016 A WHERE A.CD_UN_ORGANIZ_HIE ='X10'))
    AND MM_RA_EXEC = 6 AND AA_RA_EXEC = 2016
    AND CD_MAT = 15210001010
    GROUP BY CD_MAT
    ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 DESC;
```

And that's the result I get when I run it in IBM Acess:

### [image: IBM Acess result]

And that result is correct.

---

But when I run that same query in java using ResultSet, that's the result I get:

[image: result java's ResultSet is giving me]

---

I have no idea why this is happening. Does anyone knows what am i doing wrong?

---

That's my java code(i'm absolutely sure that the variables are right):

```
  public ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> myProblematicMethod(String cod, Integer first, Integer last) throws Excecao {

ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> lista;
lista = new ArrayList<>();

try {

  StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
  sql.append("SELECT CD_MAT , SUM(QT_MAT_UTIL) AS QT_MAT_UTIL FROM T476 ");
  sql.append(" WHERE (CD_UN_EXEC_SERV = ? OR CD_UN_EXEC_SERV ");
  sql.append(" IN (SELECT A.CD_UN_ORGANIZ FROM T016 A ");
  sql.append(" WHERE A.CD_UN_ORGANIZ_HIE = ?)) ");
  sql.append(" AND MM_RA_EXEC= ? AND AA_RA_EXEC= ? ");
  sql.append(" AND CD_MAT = 15210001010 ");
  sql.append(" GROUP BY CD_MAT ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 DESC ");

  PreparedStatement ps = this.banco.criarPS(sql.toString());

  ps.setString(1, cod);
  ps.setString(2, cod);
  ps.setInt(3, first);
  ps.setInt(4, last);

  ResultSet resultSet = this.banco.consultarSQL(ps);

  while (resultSet.next()) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> materiais = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    // campos presentes em todas as consultas realizadas
    materiais.put("cod", resultSet.getString("CD_MAT"));
    materiais.put("qnt", resultSet.getBigDecimal("QT_MAT_UTIL"));

    lista.add(materiais);
  }

      } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Excecao(e.getErrorCode(), e.getSQLState() + " - " + e.getMessage());
      }

  return lista;
  }
```

---

Java does not return any exception to me and there's no other column with that value it is returning.
I'm using java 1.8.0_65.

Comment: Did you try hardcoded values?

Comment: hi @mao, I've checked the database and the credencials, but I dont know if I understood your question, the outcome when I run the same query in IBM acess is the one in the first image(4.0000), and the outcome when I run it in ResultSet is the one in the second image(10). (the variables in java code have the same value I put in the Acess's image, i've debuged)

Comment: So maybe the criarPs thing (that you don’t show) is messed up. Avoiding PreparedStatement is not a good solution.

Comment: I'm with @NathanHughes台湾不在中国 on this one: `this.banco.criarPS` is doing **something**, and we don't know what.  I'm already a little suspicious of anything that ships a query string to something else for query preparing.  Side note: As presented, there's no reason to use a `StringBuffer` - just create it as a single `String`.  Also, there's ways to use named parameters (requires more setup, though), but possibly not your actual problem.

Comment: @NathanHughes台湾不在中国 Im looking on criarPS, i'll post here if i find anything, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing the same query in Java as the one you want.
In the PreparedStatement in Java you are missing the ' AND CD_MAT = 15210001010 ' part.

Comment: I posted wrong in here, I'll correct the question, but it still returning an wrong result (QT_MAT_UTIL  value)

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this by not using preparestatement to set the variables in the query, now I put them into the query using simple StringBuilder append and it resolved.

(I use PrepareStatement in other classes and it works fine)

Comment: **NO, ABSOLUTELY NOT**.  Using a `StringBuilder` just enabled SQL Injection (you're not validating `cod` are you?).  If `PreparedStatement` is giving you different results, you maybe have deeper issues that need to be looked into (index statistics being out of date does this, rarely, for example).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse will I still be enabeling sql injections even if I start validating the variables before bulding the sql?

Comment: You might be safe, assuming it's something trivial (Only three alphabetic ASCII characters, or something).  Anything complicated, and you're in trouble - if it's possible to include quotes in the string itself, for example.  `Integer`-based variables are _probably_ safe (hijacking them requires creating and setting as default a custom culture, which is non-trivial - although, are your app and db server set to the same culture?).  Note that prepared statements allow reusing the query plan (and might return cached objects), which might give a performance gain.

Comment: But, seriously, just use a prepared statement.  There's no good reason, here, to concatenate the variables in.  You will get safer, less error-prone, more maintainable code by doing so, and it will (probably) run faster, too.  If you're getting an error, you need to figure out why, and fix it - after all, it might eventually spread!